# Proving a collection is a $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: probability-theory

I need to prove that the collection is closed under countable unions, right? Does this imply that it is also closed under countable intersections, i.e. no need to prove the latter one separately?

Edit: Of course, I also need to prove that it is closed under complements, and that empty set is included.

Comment: Yes, you need to prove the three properties that you listed. If a collection includes the empty set, is closed under complements and closed under countable intersections, then the collection is a $\sigma$-algebra.

Answer (score 1):

If you have countable unions and complements, the countable intersection property follows, because $$X \setminus \left( \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} U_n \right) = \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( X \setminus U_n \right).$$